# Timer isn’t performed in the case of sub-task

Tags: swift, swift3

I’m trying to implement a function using timer and have found timer is not performed in case that it is called through callback function of “URLSession.dataTask”.

In below case, “callee” function is called.

```
class TimerClass {
    func caller() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1,
                                 target: self,
                                 selector: #selector(callee),
                                 userInfo: nil,
                                 repeats: false)
    }
    func callee() {
        print(“OK”)
    }
}

class AnyClass {
    func any() {
        let timer:TimerClass=TimerClass()
        timer.caller()
    }
}
```

But below “callee” is not called. (I’ve confirmed “caller” function is performed)

```
class TimerClass {
    func caller() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1,
                                 target: self,
                                 selector: #selector(callee),
                                 userInfo: nil,
                                 repeats: false)
    }
    func callee() {
        print(“OK”)
    }
}

class AnyClass {
    func any() {
        func cb(data:Data?, response:URLResponse?, err:Error?) {
            let timer:TimerClass=TimerClass()
            timer.caller()
        }
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: cb)
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

I think maybe because it was performed by sub-task.
Can anyone let me know how do I correct the code?

Answer (score 0):

Check the reference of the [`Timer` class](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/timer):

> - Use the `scheduledTimer(timeInterval:invocation:repeats:)` or `scheduledTimer(timeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:)` class
>     method to create the timer and **schedule it on the current run loop** in
>     the default mode.
> - Use the `init(timeInterval:invocation:repeats:)` or `init(timeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:)` class method to
>     create the timer object without scheduling it on a run loop. (After
>     creating it, you must add the timer to a run loop manually by calling
>     the `add(_:forMode:)` method of the corresponding RunLoop object.)

So, if you want to schedule the timer in the main RunLoop, you can write something like this:

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        Timer.scheduledTimer(
            timeInterval: 0.1,
             target: self,
             selector: #selector(self.callee),
             userInfo: nil,
             repeats: false
        )
    }
```

---

Not using the `Timer` class, but this seems to be better:

```
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
        self.callee()
    }
```

---

(UPDATED) It is clearly stated that the `RunLoop` class is generally not considered to be thread-safe. You should not use the old code (hidden in the edit history), even if it seemingly works in some limited conditions.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. That is just what I want to know and my code has became to work as my intended.

Comment: @Ken.Matushima, sorry, but I completely have forgotten to check the thread-safety of `RunLoop`, and it is clearly stated that **The `RunLoop` class is generally not considered to be thread-safe**, so please try my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for telling me. I understood. I'll search another way.

Comment: I have changed my code to above code which you corrected and confirmed it correctly works. Thank you for your support.